# Selenium return IWebElement by button text

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I have button on a webpage that looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn xs-width-100" onclick="startScreening(0, 'A', 'UK');">Start Screening</button>`
```

This button has a very similar structure to other buttons on the page. I am trying to find this element using `Selenium WebDriver`. I am currently using this:

```
return UFEElement<IWebElement>(FieldType.Link, By.XPath("//button[@class=\"btn btn-primary btn xs-width-100\"]"));
```

I can't find by `class` because the other buttons on the page have the same `class` and I can't find by `onclick` because that value changes depending are previous actions.

I have tried `By.XPath("//*[contains(text(), 'My Button')]")` and similar methods but it does not work.

I'm getting an error :-

> Error: An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code.

Is there another way to find this element?

Comment: What is the problem with this locator `By.XPath("//*[contains(text(), 'Start Screening')]")`?? is there any exception??

Comment: Error: `An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code`.

Comment: Did you look for frame/iframe?? make sure this element is not inside any frame/iframe??

Comment: It is not in an iframe

Comment: then there could be timing issue, try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until it's getting visible. try with provided answer and let me know..:)

Comment: I do use an implicit Timeout set at 30 seconds for each action that waits that time before classing it as a fail.

Comment: Try once using explicit wait using `WebDriverWait` as suggested answer and let me know..:)

Comment: Just don't mix implicit and explicit waits... bad things will happen. `WARNING: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times.` http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: What happens when you try `$x("//button[text()='Start Screening']")` in the dev toolbar on the page... does it find the element?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use css?

`button[onclick*='startScreening']` or
`button[onclick*='startScreening'][onclick*='UK']`

Answer (score 0):

> An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

It could be timing issue, you should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element is visible an clickable as below :-

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Xpth(".//button[text() = 'Start Screening']")));
```

Or you can locate it also with partial matching of `onclick` function of the element as :-

```
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("button[onclick*='startScreening']")));
```